# Understanding Mac Lane's definition of a Functor Representation

Tags: category-theory

In pg. 60 of *Categories for the Working Mathematician*:

> Let $D$ have small hom-sets. A representation of a functor $K: D
>  \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ is a pair $\langle r, \psi \rangle$, with
>   $r$ an object of $D$ and
>
> $$ \psi : D(r, -) \cong K $$
>
> a natural isomorphism. The object $r$ is called the representing
>   object. The functor $K$ is said to be representable when such a
>   representation exists.

**Question:** In this definition, does the notation $\psi : D(r, -)$ just mean that $\psi$ is another name for the functor $D(r, -)$?

Answer (score 4):

No. In fact you should read it as
$$\psi : D(r,\_)\Rightarrow K$$
so that $\psi$ is a natural transformation. Mac Lane uses $\psi : D(r,\_)\cong K$ instead to indicate that $\psi$ is an isomorphism between the two functors (which he actually repeats right after the equation anyway).